# Hangman game but I'm having troubles with a list function

Tags: python

I'm currently doing the MIT Opencourseware on Python and one of the assignments is to do a Hangman game.
Most of the functions I've managed to do pretty well but the problem I'm encountering is in these two functions:

```
def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    lengthOf = len(secret_word)

    listLength = ["_ "] *lengthOf

    for i,char in enumerate(secret_word):
        if char == letters_guessed:
            listLength[i]=char+" "
            listCopy = listLength[:]
            print(list)

def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    for i, char in enumerate(alphabet):
        if char == letters_guessed:
            alphabet[i]="_"
            alphabetCopy = alphabet[:]
            print(alphabetCopy)
            break
```

The problem is that each time I go through the function the alphabet resets and I tried solving this by creating a copy but I realized the solution really doesn't work even before implementing it because the listCopy and alphabetCopy just copy the "zero-state" each time the function is called.

I know I can do other solutions but I specifically want this "user-experience". I tried some other workarounds but I just can't figure it out right now.

Comment: One problem could be different types. I guess letter_guessed is a list and char is a String. You cannot compare String with a list with ==. Maybe you could use `in` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the variable letters_guessed is a list or set containing all letters which have been guessed.

In that case, you could use:

```py
def GetGuessedWord(SecretWord, GuessedLetters):    
    Ln = len(SecretWord)
    DisplayList = ["_ "]*Ln

    for i, char in enumerate(SecretWord):
        if char in GuessedLetters:          # This will check if char is present in the list
            DisplayList[i] = char + " "
    print(DisplayList)

def GetAvailableLetters(GuessedLetters):
    Letters = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    DisplayList = [L for L in Letters]      # Converts it into a list of smaller strings, 1 letter each

    for i, char in enumerate(DisplayList):
        if char in GuessedLetters:
            DisplayList[i] = "_"
    print(DisplayList)
```

```
>>> GetGuessedWord("overgrown", ['o'])
['o ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', 'o ', '_ ', '_ ']
>>> GetGuessedWord("overgrown", ['o', 'e', 'r'])
['o ', '_ ', 'e ', 'r ', '_ ', 'r ', 'o ', '_ ', '_ ']
>>> GetGuessedWord("overgrown", ['o','e','r','z'])
['o ', '_ ', 'e ', 'r ', '_ ', 'r ', 'o ', '_ ', '_ ']


>>> GetAvailableLetters(['o'])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'k', 'm', 'n', '_', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> GetAvailableLetters(['o', 'e', 'r'])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '_', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'k', 'm', 'n', '_', 'p', 'q', '_', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> GetAvailableLetters(['o', 'e', 'r', 'z'])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '_', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'k', 'm', 'n', '_', 'p', 'q', '_', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', '_']
```

The '==' operator returns true if the objects being compared have the same value. It will return false since one is a string and the other a list, hence can't have same value.

The 'in' operator returns true if the input on the left is present in the input in the right.

### However

If you are guessing one letter at a time, then you need your functions to leave permanent modifications on the variables outside. So variable alphabet can't be declared inside get_available_letters, but must be declared in the main code and passed as an input to the function get_available_letters. This should fix this function if letters_guessed is a string 1 letter long. Now you can use the '==' operator.

```py
def get_available_letters(letters_guessed, alphabet):
    for i, char in enumerate(alphabet):
        if char == letters_guessed:
            alphabet[i]="_"               # This line will permanently change the variable alphabet
            alphabetCopy = alphabet[:]    # Not useful, u may as well print the original
            print(alphabetCopy)
            break
```

```
>>> alphabet = [L for L in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']; print(alphabet)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

>>> get_available_letters("o", alphabet)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', '_', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> get_available_letters("e", alphabet)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '_', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', '_', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> get_available_letters("r", alphabet)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '_', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', '_', 'p', 'q', '_', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> get_available_letters("z", alphabet)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '_', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', '_', 'p', 'q', '_', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', '_']
```

For the other function you would need variable listLength to be declared outside and passed to this function.

```py
def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed, listLength):
    for i,char in enumerate(secret_word):
        if char == letters_guessed:
            listLength[i]=char+" "                # Permanently modifies listLength, not breaking since multiple same letters can occur in the same word
listCopy = listLength[:]
print(listCopy)
```

```
>>> secret_word = "overgrown"
>>> listLength = ["_ "]*len(secret_word); print(listLength)
['_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ']

>>> get_guessed_word(secret_word, "o", listLength)
['o ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', 'o ', '_ ', '_ ']
>>> get_guessed_word(secret_word, "e", listLength)
['o ', '_ ', 'e ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', 'o ', '_ ', '_ ']
>>> get_guessed_word(secret_word, "r", listLength)
['o ', '_ ', 'e ', 'r ', '_ ', 'r ', 'o ', '_ ', '_ ']
>>> get_guessed_word(secret_word, "z", listLength)
['o ', '_ ', 'e ', 'r ', '_ ', 'r ', 'o ', '_ ', '_ ']
```

And make copies of arrays when you need to modify arrays without affecting the original.

Comment: Thats a perfect answer my dude. Thank you.

Comment: I knew that I could have done it outside of the local scope but I thought maybe there was another way. Unfortunately not. Thank you again man.

Answer (score 0):

### get_available_letters

So you have a list with letters that were already guessed and you want to know, what letters are left.
The simplest way is to use `sets`.

```
def get_available_letters(guessed_letters):
   alphabet = set(map(chr, range(97, 123))) # Same list like you but shorter version
   return sorted(alphabet - set(guessed_letters))
```

What this does:

```
>>>get_available_letters(['a', 'e', 'f'])
['b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

### get_guessed_word

```
def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
   guessed_word = ["_"] * len(secret_word)
   for i, letter in enumerate(secret_word):
      if letter in letters_guessed: # Changed == to in
         guessed_word[i] = letter # Don't break after a letter was found and no copy necessary
   return "".join(guessed_word)
```

```
>>>get_guessed_word("Hello", ["e", "o"])
'_e__o'
```

Comment: That is a bit outside of my learning scope since I have yet to learn sets but I appreciate you introducing me to a new concept. Thank you Uli.